# How to join Two tupples using SPARK-shell

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to join two text file using Spark-shell command. I have written following codes.

```
val a = sc.parallelize(List(("symbol", "CNN"), ("symbol", "CND")))
val b = sc.parallelize(List(("symbol", "CNN"), ("symbol1", "CNN")))
val joned = a.join(b)
```

but its showing an error Join is not a member of org.apache.Spark.
can any one suggest me how to achieve the join.

Comment: I can run your code in spark-shell. Can you paste the error information?

Answer (score 1):

Your missing an implicit conversion in your scope to a Pair RDD (has notion of key and value), so all you need to do is first run:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
```